# Spring Boot - mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In the code below there are two methods annotated with `@GetMapping` annotation, one expects empty path, another one expects a path variable.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BasicController {

  @GetMapping()
  public String get(Model model) {
    // doing something
  }

  @GetMapping("/{variable}")
  public String getWithPathVar(@PathVariable("variable") String variable, Model model) {
    // doing something different
  }
}
```

Problem: When the app is running and I hit "www.myurl.com/" it enters both methods even though there is no path parameter. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried by removing @RequestMapping("/") from the controller and then putting 
  @GetMapping("/") on the first get method and   @GetMapping("/{variable}") on the second getWithPathVar() method

Comment: I tried a lot of different combination, but apparently not this one :)
This one helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If so it sounds like a bug or some misconfiguration with filters. I can't reproduce this behaviour on the Spring `5.2.7`. Here's an [article](https://ddcode.net/2019/06/22/how-does-spring-mvc-calculate-best-_-matching-_-pattern-_-attribute/) that explains how Spring works under the hood.

If you can't upgrade the Spring version you can use only single endpoint as a workaround.

```
@GetMapping("/{variable}")
public String getWithPathVar(@PathVariable("variable") String variable, Model model) {
  // doing something different
 if(variable != null) {
   // fulfill the normal workflow
 } else {
   // call ex get() workflow
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Spring v5.2.8, with default configuration :(

Comment that @implosivesilence added helped...

Comment: As I already mentioned above, I can't reproduce it, even for `5.2.8`. By the way, what do you return in these two methods? The once more important thing: you use `@Controller` with endpoints without `@ResponseBody` instead of `@RestController`.  In this case, the return value should be interpreted  by Spring as a view name